# Error getting class type with wxIS_KIND_OF macro

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I'm trying to get a *wxSizer* class type with **wxIS_KIND_OF** macro.
After few seconds my program finish without show the main window of my app.

This is the code:

```
wxXmlResource::Get()->LoadFrame((wxFrame*)this,  (wxWindow*)NULL , wxT("MyFrame1"));

wxPanel* container = (wxPanel*)FindWindowByName("m_panel1");
if (!container){
    cout << "Error loading container!" << endl << flush;
}
else{
    for (unsigned int i=0; i<3; i++){
        auxPanelArray[i] = new wxPanel( container, wxID_ANY, wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, wxTAB_TRAVERSAL );
        wxXmlResource::Get()->LoadPanel( auxPanelArray[i] , wxT("MyPanel6"));

        wxSizer* mySizer = auxPanelArray[i]->GetSizer();
        if (wxIS_KIND_OF(mySizer, wxStaticBoxSizer)){
            cout << "Your sizer is a wxStaticBoxSizer" << endl << flush;
            ((wxStaticBoxSizer*)mySizer)->GetStaticBox()->SetLabel("My new label");
        }

        container->GetSizer()->Add(auxPanelArray[i]);
    }
}
```

In my XRC, the sizer type is wxStaticBoxSizer, so wxIS_KIND_OF should detect it and enter inside the if block.

Why it doesn't work?

***UPDATE***
This is the XRC file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<resource xmlns="http://www.wxwindows.org/wxxrc" version="2.3.0.1">
    <object class="wxPanel" name="MyPanel6">
        <style>wxTAB_TRAVERSAL</style>
        <object class="wxStaticBoxSizer">
            <minsize>100,100</minsize>
            <orient>wxVERTICAL</orient>
            <label>label</label>
            <object class="sizeritem">
                <option>1</option>
                <flag>wxEXPAND|wxALL</flag>
                <border>5</border>
                <object class="wxBoxSizer">
                    <orient>wxHORIZONTAL</orient>
                    <object class="sizeritem">
                        <option>0</option>
                        <flag>wxALL</flag>
                        <border>5</border>
                        <object class="wxStaticText" name="m_staticText12">
                            <label>MyLabel</label>
                            <wrap>-1</wrap>
                        </object>
                    </object>
                    <object class="sizeritem">
                        <option>0</option>
                        <flag>wxALL</flag>
                        <border>5</border>
                        <object class="wxTextCtrl" name="m_textCtrl4">
                            <value></value>
                        </object>
                    </object>
                </object>
            </object>
            <object class="sizeritem">
                <option>0</option>
                <flag>wxALL</flag>
                <border>5</border>
                <object class="wxButton" name="m_button8">
                    <label>MyButton</label>
                    <default>0</default>
                </object>
            </object>
        </object>
    </object>
</resource>
```

Comment: ????  What is wxIS_KIND_OF?

Comment: That is a macro that wraps the method IsKindOf(), that implements all classes that derivates from wxObject. It is defined in file object.h

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wxIS_KIND_OF()` must, of course, work for `wxStaticBoxSizer`, so either the sizer is not of this type or your code is actually executing but doesn't have any effect because your standard output isn't shown anywhere -- which is the case by default in GUI applications under Windows.

I'd also advise to use `wxDynamicCast()` instead of `wxIS_KIND_OF`:

```
wxStaticBoxSizer* boxSizer = wxDynamicCast(mySizer, wxStaticBoxSizer);
if ( boxSizer ) {
   ... just use it now, no need for more casts ...
}
```

Comment: wxDynamicCast is nice. The problem wasn't the stdout. When I do auxPanelArray[i]->GetSizer() and then make the cast, it always return null. I think that's because, depending the wxPanel there is a wxStaticBoxSizer instead a wxBoxSizer. Could be?

Comment: OK, I has a bug on LoadFrame() line. Changing that line by auxPanelArray[i] = wxXmlResource::Get()->LoadPanel( container , wxT("MyPanel6")); make it works. Thanks again VZ